# Android - XML Parser App

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app which parses an XML file from the server using SAX and displays in the form of list. I'm getting null pointer exception. But when i excecuted the same code as java application removing all the android stuffs i'm able to print the list which wanted to display in the list. It's document of about 700 items.
I couldn't understand much from the logs i got using Logcat. I'm new to android development. It would really helpful if you can help me with this.

```
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rss.com/rss.com.RSSReader}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at rss.com.RSSReader.onCreate(RSSReader.java:33)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403):     ... 11 more
```

My Manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="rss.com"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".RSSReader"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ShowDescription" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Java code:

```
public class RSSReader extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public RSSFeed feed=null;
    public List<RSSItem> list = null;
    public final static String RSSFEEDOFCHOICE = "http://people.rit.edu/~vxr9024/chemicalFeed.xml";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);
    list = feed.getAllItems();
    UpdateDisplay(list);
}

RSSFeed getFeed(String urlToRssFeed)
{
    FeedParser parsedFeed = new FeedParser(); 
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlToRssFeed);
        XMLReader xread = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        xread.setContentHandler(parsedFeed);
        InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
        xread.parse(is);
        return parsedFeed.getFeed();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
    }catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Blahblah");
    return null;
    }
}

private void UpdateDisplay(List<RSSItem> list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RSSItem[] items = new RSSItem[list.size()]; 
    list.toArray(items);
    ListView itemlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemlist);
    //RSSItem[] items = new RSSItem[()]; 
    ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            items);
    itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    itemlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    itemlist.setSelection(0);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intentItem = new Intent(this,ShowDescription.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("chemicalName",feed.getItem(position).getChemicalName());
    b.putString("synonyms",feed.getItem(position).getSynonyms());
    b.putString("formula",feed.getItem(position).getFormula());
    intentItem.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);
    startActivity(intentItem);
}
}
```

Comment: You got a NullPointerException hidden in there

13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 06-08 13:27:04.032: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(403): at rss.com.RSSReader.onCreate(RSSReader.java:33)

Comment: feed = getFeed(RSSFEEDOFCHOICE);
list = feed.getAllItems();
List of items that was parsed from a different class.

Comment: Seems like getFeed() is returns null, you must check out why.

Comment: I'm able to print out the items if i just execute as a java app !
It is a simple issue but couldn't really figure it out why it does show Null pointer exception.

Comment: I have added the source code of the file where it is coming from.

Comment: Is there another exception, or "Blahblah" in the logcat prior to this Null pointer exception?  You need to find out which exception is thrown in your getFeed method which is causing it to return null.  I would put a breakpoint in each of the exception handlers and see which is getting thrown.  Beyond that we don't have enough info yet to help.

Comment: Nope there isn't any. Its really weird why getFeed() returns null when i call it from onCreate() and not when i just used a main class and executed as a java app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Otherwise the app can't use Internet to read you rss ?