# Android App using data from an Excel file

Tags: android

I'm new to android development. I have to make an Android app using data from an Excel sheet. I thought it will be easy if i generate XML document using PHP and use it as a feed for the app so that it can be updated anytime. But it seems to be not working for me.

I had already posted a question regarding this.
[Android - XML Parser App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279609/android-xml-parser-app)

So now I'm thinking about the other ways to make the app using the data from an excel sheet. It is about 700 rows X 18 columns.

Please give me some suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: The original option of serving the XML via PHP will work.  Keep trying at it.

Comment: I wrote pretty decent application following a tutorial and i'm trying to figure out what is going wrong since yesterday. Haven't got an answer yet :(
I can share the source code and if anybody can resolve it, that would be great !

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing some code in the Google IO 2010 application that read data from an excel spreadsheet.  I would check out Google's [source code](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) for an example.  They might have updated it and taken out the code, but you should be able to see past revisions with the code still present.